# How to set/override Lit-Element typescript property decorator by parsing value in index.html custom element?

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I am trying to override a set property in lit-element. I am using Typescript and I am setting the value using a decorator in the custom element, although when I try to override the element by setting a different attribute in the index.html it doesn't overwrite...

When I console.log the attribute the it only has the attribute set in the lit-element.

I am using mixinBehaviours, IronA11yKeysBehavior and GestureEventListeners with LitElement.

The property does overwrite when using the normal javascript notation, although if possible I would prefer to keep decorators if possible.

```
// TypeScript file

class Carousel extends mixinBehaviors([
  IronA11yKeysBehavior,
  GestureEventListeners
], LitElement) {

  /**
   * Carousel direction (horizontal or vertical)
   */
  @property({type: String})
  direction = 'horizontal';
}

// index.html
<carousel direction="vertical"></carousel>
```

I am hoping that the direction in index.html can override the typescript decorator property...

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the attribute, not the property. Setting the property would be `.direction`. You can find a syntax reference here: https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#bind-to-properties